# Smooth Schoenflies theorem for compact $3$-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $M^3$ be a compact $3$-manifold with $\partial M=N$ a connected surface. Suppose one has a smooth embedding of $N$ into the interior of $M$ and $N$ bounds a domain $D$ in $M$. Can we show that $D$ is homeomorphic to $M$?

Comment: This is certainly not true. One class of examples is given by the complements of satellite knots: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_knot. These contain tori that are not parallel to the boundary, and indeed these tori  bound a "deeper" knot complement.

Comment: If you drop the dimensions down to $2$, it is also not true.     There is however a way to phrase it for curves.

Comment: This is true only if M is the 3-ball.

Comment: @BrunoMartelli Why not for other handlebodies?

Comment: You can embed a surface of genus >= 1 inside a ball in a strange way, so that it does not bound a handlebody in it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this need not hold.

Here is a concrete example.  Suppose that $K \subset S^3$ is the trefoil knot in the three-sphere.  It is an old result (certainly known to Alexander) that $K$ is not isotopic to the unknot.  Let $N(K)$ be a small tubular neighbourhood of $K$, taken in $S^3$.  So $N(K)$ is a solid torus.  Let $n(K)$ be the interior of $N(K)$.  We define $M = S^3 - n(K)$.  This is a (compact) *knot exterior*.  By the "old result" $M$ is not homeomorphic to a solid torus.  Note that $T = \partial M = \partial N(K)$ is a two-torus.

Now choose an embedded loop $\alpha$ in $M$.  Then $N(\alpha)$, a small tubular neighbourhood of $\alpha$, is another solid torus.  Again $T' = \partial N(\alpha)$ is a two-torus.  However, $N(\alpha)$ is not homeomorphic to $M$.

The comments above give many other examples.  In general, the ways that a fixed surface embeds into a fixed three-manifold is an interesting question.